# Nonexistence of limit

Tags: calculus, limits

Is the following statement true or false:

$$
\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} n^k [1-(\lambda t)/n - o(1/n)]^{n -k} = \exp(-\lambda t)
$$

$\lambda,t,k$ are given constants.

I'm thinking I can show the falsity of the statement simple by assuming the truth of the statement and then taking $\log$ on both sides to get divergence on LHS while constant on RHS but I'm not entirely sure whether such an argument could be made valid...any hints or advice would be appreciated. By the way this is not homework although the purpose is educational.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you asking if $$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} ln(f(n)) = ln(c)$$ for all $f$ where $$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} f(n) = c \quad ?$$
If so, the answer is no. The domain of $ln$ is $\mathcal{R}_{>0}$ and the image of $f$ might not be contained in $\mathcal{R}_{>0}$ (but otherwise this holds, because $ln$ is differentiable, and everything else follows from definition of $\lim$).

However, if you include a proof that your LHS $>0$ for all $n>N$ for some $N$, your suggested approach seems sound to me. In particular it would seem that while a term of your LHS approaches 0, it never actually equals 0, which is enough for what you want.

Comment: ok so what I was doing was simply to take log to get : k log n + (n-k)log [1-lamda*t/n - o(1/n)] and knowing that n>k > 0. the problem you are mentioning shouldn't apply?

Comment: My intention was to make the preconditions clear of your approach.  So that we know your approach is sound.  Wasn't that the question?

Comment: Yes preconditions were part of the question. The falsity of the statement being another part. I am not very practised at finding limits, and it is a the statement is made as part of a proof I'm reading where I suspect a typo. I would assume that (n-k)log[1-lamda*t/n - o(1/n)]  goes to -lambda*t while k log n goes to infinity making the sum diverge.

Comment: Anyway noting that [1-lamda*t/n - o(1/n)] > 0 at least for all n > N this is what I get using the rule you stated and hence accept the answer. Thx.